# Samsung Galaxy Player 5.0 won't turn on after messing with build.prop

Tags: adb

I went to mess with my build.prop to do some stuff and then my device wouldnt turn on. I tried looking everywhere for ways to fix it but none will work because it keeps ending with when im in cmd with the adb stuff, when I type the commands it says "operation not permitted".

Heres the tutorial I was looking at (the wndows one) - http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1927198

I was able to get to the very end until I had to do "chmod 644 build.prop" which then resulted in the "operation not permitted".

I also have a copy of my original build.prop in my device sdcard folder however Im unable to pull it out (or im just an idiot)

Please help, ive been sitting here for 6 hours straight trying to fix this!

Comment: Have you tried `sudo chmod 644 build.prop`? The error message you report sounds like you're not in "root mode", which `sudo` should fix.

Comment: I did however nothing seemed to happen.

Comment: So no error message? Then you should have succeeded :) try `ls -l build.prop`. It should list the permissions as `-rw-r--r--` (which corresponds to `644` for a file).

Comment: Actually nvm, the sudo did get an error msg saying "sudo: not found"

Comment: What should I do then?

Comment: Oh, forgive me... It's simply `su` on Android. Full day working on Linux, so I messed up, sorry. So could you try with `su chmod 644 build.prop` again and state whether there was any message, plus the result of above `ls` for verification?

Comment: the command repeated itself and then when I went into ls it said -rwxrwxr-x

Comment: So it did not work.

Comment: So no error message, no change, nothing? Sorry, then I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're rooted?
If so, have you tried `su -c chmod 0644 /system/build.prop`? Or you can also try entering `su` first and then the `chmod` command next.

To pull the build.prop: `adb pull /sdcard/build.prop`
Or maybe you can just replace the one in `/system` with the one on your sdcard:

```
su
cp /sdcard/build.prop /system/build.prop
chmod 0644 /system/build.prop
```